# Avoiding copying and pasting text by using Microsoft Outlook or a third-party web app?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, salesforce

I was wondering if there was tool available that would automate copying and pasting form emails from a Word document into another program (Salesforce comments).

I envision something where a user could drag a button and it would copy text with it into a new field.

To explain, I am helping a low-tech savvy, resource-strapped team avoid copying and pasting form emails. They currently use a Microsoft Word document with over fifty messages that they copy and paste into a separate program. As you can imagine, there is a lot of scrolling and searching for the right message depending on circumstance, not to mention room for human error with the copying and pasting.

We are looking to automate this in some way and would love some suggestions.